# Very short science fiction movie where clones are revived in a space ship, make observations and then die

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I saw this within the past 15 years on public tv. An astronaut is sent on a mission or maybe just his clones. They need someone to make observations of stellar phenomena but after this, the clone is flushed into space. I would like to know title/who created it.

Comment: I don't think it is the film you are seeking. But this sounds similar in theme to the 2009 film Moon.  It has a lunar astronaut/space worker at a helium mining and observation post who discovers he is a clone of the original astronaut. Without giving too many spoilers there are some other similarities as well. if you liked the other, you might like this one as well.  if you are interested more details can be found at the following. But beware spoilers:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_(film)

Comment: @beichst: no, it is like a 10 minute film.

Comment: It also sounds similar to the 2016 Red Dwarf episode _[Officer Rimmer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5218284/)_, where a deep space ship is on auto-pilot, unmanned, except in emergencies, in which case a copy of a human crewmember is bio-printed to take care of things (and then discarded when no longer needed). This ep is 28 minutes.

Comment: But it is not a Red Dwarf. It is very sad with the clone sort of making up a prayer. Quite poignant.

Comment: @Jeff Can you edit the question and put that in? The more info in the question body itself, the better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the 2000 short film [Today's Life](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0262049/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)?

It runs about 7 minutes total for the first part (about 13 minutes overall) and matches several points in your description including clone termination, space exploration, etc.

> *"Today's Life is one of the few entertaining short films that's more about plot and less about symbolism. In just 13 minutes, it tells the
>   story of a future NASA-like agency that sends out space ships filled
>   with cloned astronauts to explore the far reaches of the galaxy. These
>   clones are supposed to lack any memory of their life before being
>   cloned, and function only as robots. This is an emotional story
>   because both the main character and the audience knows that he is
>   about to be "terminated" once he finishes the job. It's a highbrow
>   story because it makes the audience question the morality behind human
>   cloning. Are human clones simply disposable objects without a soul, to
>   be thrown away when they are no longer needed?"*

Comment: This is it, thanks.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  As I mentioned above, if you liked this one, you might enjoy the full length movie Moon. Similar themes.

Comment: I have of course heard of Moon and may check it out. To me the ultimate exploration of this theme is probably Think Like a Dinosaur, a well-crafted short story that worked well as an Outer Limits (not the original series but a later incarnation) episode.

Comment: Agreed. I have seen that episode as well.  'balance the equation' .  Quite the ethical dilemma.

Comment: it is not just the moral dilemma to me; it is the fundamental question about what really happens when you "beam up" in Star Trek which in fact characters have asked about in later incarnations of the show. In fact, Star Trek in the episode where the guy had made himself into an android sort of looks this theme from a different angle and people today are thinking about this for real: are we our memories, etc. so if you make a copy of a mind is it you or just a copy who thinks it's you? in TLAD, obviously the woman would not have find complete solace in knowing a copy of her existed.